# In SOAP i got a property as a json. How to pull properties from there and make new string

Tags: c#, json, soap

In SOAP i got a property as a json. How to pull properties from there and make new string.
[image]

```
public string Lisainfo { get; set; }
```

[image]

But i need only one property from this json string "Lehekylg":{"JrnNr:4"}. I need to get this number 4..how can i do that ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that represents the json property.

```
    public class LisaInfo
    {
        public string Failinimi { get; set; }
        public string ObjectId { get; set; }
        public string LehekyldegeArv { get; set; }
        public Lehekylg Lehekylg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lehekylg
    {
        public int JrkNr { get; set; }
    }
```

And then:

```
var li = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LisaInfo>(Lisainfo)
```

disclaimer: check spelling